# Error on Zend controller creation

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, mamp

I'm attempting to build a test project with the Zend framework and using MAMP to run it on my local host.

The project creation works fine; I navigate to my htdocs directory and use `zf create project my_zend` to create the scaffold.

My error comes when I try to create a controller "students" by using the following command `zf create controller students`, however, once this command runs it outputs the following error:

> Context by name servicesDirectory does not exist in the registry.

Where does this error come from?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, here is how  I fixed it, check for the line:

```
<servicesDirectory enabled="false"/>
```

In the .zfproject.xml file and remove it.

Comment: Please elaborate further. What does removing this line do?

Comment: According to my knowledge this has something to do with the Zend path. Just went through the `zfproject.xml` file and found out this line.

Answer (score 1):

You might get this error if you have another version of zend some where in the path. If you have one try deleting it and using the latest or the version you wish to. This worked for me in xamp on windows 7 hope it works for you